# How to determine height and width of text in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble with getting a block of text to be in the center of the page.
This is the text I am trying to center:

```
<div id="DIRECTIONS">
    <h2>Use the keyboard to rotate a face of the cube in a clockwise direction!
    <br>Hold down the shift key to rotate the desired face counter-clockwise.
    <br>Use your mouse to rotate the cube and zoom in and out.</h2>
</div>
```

In my Cascading Style Sheet, I have the following:

```
#DIRECTIONS{
    position:absolute;
    top:80px;
    left:31.5%;
    text-align:center;
}
```

With the above code, the text is (somewhat) centered in my browser when it is fullscreen. When I change the size of the browser, the text becomes awkwardly shifted and not centered at all. I know I need to specify the height and width of the text, but is there an easier way to do it? Or could someone help me out with what the height and width of this text will be?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A centered layout works like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="DIRECTIONS">
    <h2>Use the keyboard to rotate a face of the cube in a clockwise direction!
    <br>Hold down the shift key to rotate the desired face counter-clockwise.
    <br>Use your mouse to rotate the cube and zoom in and out.</h2>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#DIRECTIONS
{
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

Give the inner DIV a specific width and set margin left and right to auto. This will center it. That's actually the way most centered layouts work. It also looks good even if the browser window is smaller than the actual content.

**jsFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/o4exkcjo/

Answer (score 2):

you can drop position and use display instead:

---

Run the snippets un full page mode :)

---

```css
#DIRECTIONS {
  display:table;
  margin:auto;
  background:gray;/* demo purpose */
  font-size:1vw;
  }
```

```html
<div id="DIRECTIONS">
    <h2>Use the keyboard to rotate a face of the cube in a clockwise direction!
    <br>Hold down the shift key to rotate the desired face counter-clockwise.
    <br>Use your mouse to rotate the cube and zoom in and out.</h2>
</div>
```

or

```css
html {
  height:100%;/* so can middle center too :) */
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  }
body {
  margin:auto;
  }
#DIRECTIONS{
  background:gray;
  font-size:1vw;
  }
```

```html
<div id="DIRECTIONS">
    <h2>Use the keyboard to rotate a face of the cube in a clockwise direction!
    <br>Hold down the shift key to rotate the desired face counter-clockwise.
    <br>Use your mouse to rotate the cube and zoom in and out.</h2>
</div>
```

`position:absolute;`, unless use for wellknown purpose should be avoided :)

---

BONUS: another table like display

```css
html {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  display:table;
  }
body {
  display:table-cell;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
  }
#DIRECTIONS {
  display:inline-block;
  background:gray;
  text-align:left;
  font-size:1vw;
  }
```

```html
<div id="DIRECTIONS">
    <h2>Use the keyboard to rotate a face of the cube in a clockwise direction!
    <br>Hold down the shift key to rotate the desired face counter-clockwise.
    <br>Use your mouse to rotate the cube and zoom in and out.</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Centering an unknown `height` and `width` element for both horizontally and vertically can be done as simple as follows.

```
.element {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```css
.element {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
     Hello World!
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use good old table to center any content both vertically and horizontally, combined with fixed or absolute position.

```css
html, body {
    position: relative;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
#directions {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    text-align: center;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: none rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
#directions h2 {
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<table id="directions">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                 <h2>Use the keyboard to rotate a face of the cube in a clockwise direction!<br />
            Hold down the shift key to rotate the desired face counter-clockwise.<br />
            Use your mouse to rotate the cube and zoom in and out.</h2>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**[Fiddle playground](http://jsfiddle.net/ogboazq7/)** - used as a modal dialog.